# Extracting Sequences from Padded DNA Sequences

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with two columns, 'padded_seq' and 'seq', where 'padded_seq' contains padded DNA sequences, and 'seq' contains target sequences.

Simple example DataFrame:

```
    padded_seq  seq      
0     AATTGGC  TTG                 
1     AATTGGC  TTG                 
2     AATTGGC  TTG                
3     CGTACGC  TAC                 
4     CGTACGC  TAC                 
5     CGTACGC  TAC
```

I need to extract sequences from 'padded_seq' based on the 'seq' column, considering a window of 4 nucleotides around each character in 'seq'. For each character in 'seq', I want to create a new row with the extracted sequence.

Here's the expected output (for taking +/-2 nucleotides):

```
    padded_seq  seq      single_letter_padded (separated for clarity)
0     AATTGGC  TTG                 AA T TG
0     AATTGGC  TTG                 AT T GG
0     AATTGGC  TTG                 TT G GC
1     CGTACGC  TAC                 CG T AC
1     CGTACGC  TAC                 GT A CG
1     CGTACGC  TAC                 TA C GC
```

I would appreciate help to find an efficient way as I have millions of rows.
Here's what I have (kernel keeps dying though):

```
# Function to extract sequences based on the given window size
half_window=250 #250 per side

def extract_sequences(df, half_window=250):
    padded_single_nucleotides_list = []
    for y in range(len(df['padded_sequences'])):
        for x in range(df['seq_len'][y]):
            padded_single_nucleotides_list.append(df['padded_sequences'][y][(half_window+x)-half_window:(half_window+x)+half_window+1])
            
    return padded_single_nucleotides_list

#to make sure the seq_df is the correct num of rows-- shouldn't have to do this (use explode?), not sure how to get around it
seq_df=seq_df.loc[np.repeat(seq_df.index, seq_df['seq_len'])].reset_index(drop=True)

# Apply the function to each row and explode the list into separate rows
seq_df['single_nucl_padded'] = extract_sequences(seq_df, half_window=250)

# Display the result
seq_df
```

Any guidance or code snippets would be appreciated!

Comment: Why does `single_letter_padded` only have 4 characters for index 1? Also, it's unclear from your sample data as to what exactly `window_size` is supposed to do. And with a window size of 250, what happens if `seq` occurs more than once?

Comment: Can you provide more sample data and expected result that more clearly demonstrates your logic?

Comment: The example I posted had a window size of 4 (because 2 nucleotides on each side)- technically perhaps 'window' isn't the best word since the window would actually be 4+1=5 nucleotides (include the middle one)

Comment: @Nick I just made some edits to my example for clarity.

Comment: I did get the algorithm, I was just confused by your code. From the original code you posted, it seems `padded_seq` can be quite long. What are the possible lengths of `padded_seq` and `seq`? And can `seq` occur more than once in `padded_seq`? If so, do you want all results or a specific one?

Comment: Also, what if there aren't sufficient pad characters e.g. if `pad=2`, `padded_seq = GTACG`, `seq = TAC`, is the result just `GTACG` or should `GTAC` and `TACG` also be included?